# Where does go put imports when using modules with no GOPATH set?

Tags: go, module, go-modules

I'm toying around with converting a project at work to be a module. My understanding is it should make deploys much easier since $GOPATH won't have to be set up properly.

In my existing project I ran `go mod init <project path>`, and checked in `go.mod` and `go.sum`. As a test, I opened a new terminal, `unset GOPATH`, cloned my project into /tmp, `go build`, and everything worked great but it left me with questions. I expected my imports to be downloaded into a vendor folder but nothing.

Where does go modules put the packages it has to `go get` when no $GOPATH is set?

Comment: default `GOPATH` is `$HOME/go/...`

Comment: @nilsocket, Sure enough, there's the stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [modules help](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-GOPATH_and_Modules):

> When using modules, GOPATH is no longer used for resolving imports. However, it is still used to store downloaded source code (in GOPATH/pkg/mod) and compiled commands (in GOPATH/bin).

So in your case if GOPATH is unset it will use the default GOPATH (`$HOME/go/`) and thereby store the cached imports in: `$HOME/go/pkg/mod`